# Testing plain javascript Vue components without Vue CLI

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2017, jestjs, components, vue-test-utils

Is it possible to test Vue components that were developped in plain javascript without a Vue CLI/Webpack/Babel setup?

The documentation on the subjet I found so far on the Web is pretty slim :

- https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/1192
- https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/installation/#running-vue-test-utils-without-a-build-step
- [How to test plain Vue components (not single file components)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55052983/how-to-test-plain-vue-components-not-single-file-components)

I installed Vue, Vue test utils, JSDOM

**My package.json :**

```
{
  "name": "GuichetUnique.CMS",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "jest": "^26.4.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.5",
    "jsdom": "16.4.0",
    "jsdom-global": "3.0.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Jest is running fine with simple js functions but I haven't manage to test a Vue component.

**The content of my test**

```
require('jsdom-global')();
var testUtils = require('@vue/test-utils'), Vue = require('vue');

testUtils.mount({ template: '<div>test</div>' });
```

**The test result**

```
TypeError: Illegal invocation at removeEventListener (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventTarget.js:157:15)
```

[image]

Please help !

Comment: I hope this can help you. `Deprecation Notice: When stubbing components, supplying a string (ComponentToStub: '<div class="stubbed" />) is no longer supported.`  [Link](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#mount)

Comment: Thank you Dilip. I'll explore the API further

Comment: `TypeError: Illegal invocation at removeEventListener` this error code shows that you are trying to remove an event listener that does not exist. Please check your code in detail.

Comment: May I ask why you don't want to use the VUE-cli?

Comment: Thanks you for your question Eliezer. Basically, the Idea behind not choosing to use the Vue-Cli is that all our components are already written un plain javascript without any build step. We're looking to add unit testing to put code without disrupting to much the development workflow of a team of 6 developpers. Now maybe the overhead of using the Vue-Cli is worth it but we would like to weight our options first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've had a similar issue 2 months ago. A slightly different use case but for us the dependency on VueCLI in specific was the culprit. Without it, we found no way of successfully running even basic tests.

I think that if you want to go this route, you might have to do a lot of work bypassing the intended mechanisms. For that you need to answer yourself if that is worth your time. We went with the VueCLI and took the overhead for granted.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Ozone. I have to agree with you. The vue-Cli provides so much out of the box. Maybe the overhead is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this a year ago, where i came across the similar situation where I do not want to use CLI/webpack.

Hope fully it can add some contribution in solving your query.

To test your component without webpack you can use  [http-vue-loader](https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/http-vue-loader) plugin.

**The plugin workflow is simple**

1. http request the vue file
2. load the vue file in a document fragment
3. process each section (template, script and style)
4. return a promise to Vue.js (async components)
5. then Vue.js compiles and cache the component

Actually the main purpose of plugin is to quickly test `vue` components without any compilation step. However, for production, I recommend to use webpack module bundler with vue-loader.

[Refer to a Example here](https://codepen.io/cscolabear/project/editor/AQLQLO)

Comment: Thanks Saddam. What about the testing part? Could you provide an example with testing a component written un plain javascript (not .vue files) with vue test utils and Jest?